# adviceID 139 doesn't exist didChangeAdviceID

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, skmaps

In skobbler map,

```
 -(void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didChangeAdviceID:(int)adviceID
```

This delegate method get an '`adviceID`' 139. using this from the below code this adviceID is not existing.

```
-(void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didChangeAdviceID:(int)adviceID
{
        NSArray* advicesArray = [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] routeAdviceListWithDistanceFormat:SKDistanceFormatMetric];
        SKRouteAdvice *advice = advicesArray[adviceID];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.2.0/Protocols/SKNavigationDelegate.html#//api/name/routingService:didChangeAdviceID:): "Called when the unique ID of the current advice is changed. Consistent with the adviceID from the SKRouteAdvice."

So it's normal that the advice id was changed - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In 'didChangeAdviceID' we are getting current id right ?, so I can get the current advice from the advice array.